# Saving a user entered file name c++

Tags: c++, qt

I am writing a program to save a text file where the user enters the file name. I have opened a window to set the name of the file but once I hit save I get the error: "QFSFileEngine::open: No file name specified"

I have written code that specifies the directory and the filename and that works perfectly, but once I try and have the user enter the filename I am no longer able to have the file save to any directory and I get the above error message.

///// this is the code that gets me the error:

```
void MainWindow::on_pushButton_clicked()
{
    QFile file;
    QString filename = QFileDialog::getSaveFileName(this, tr("save 
        document"), QDir::currentPath(), tr("documents(*.txt"));
    if(!file.open(QFile::WriteOnly | QFile::Text)){
        QMessageBox::warning(this, "title", "file not open");
    }
}
```

///// this is the code that works:

```
void MainWindow::on_pushButton_clicked()
 {
    QFile file("C:/Users/orlan/Desktop/test");
    if(!file.open(QFile::WriteOnly | QFile::Text)){
        QMessageBox::warning(this, "title", "file not open");
    }
}
```

The expected result is the user saves a file with with a chosen name but the actual result is an error message of: "QFSFileEngine::open: No file name specified" and no file being saved.

Comment: In the first example you made no use of the filename. I think you are missing a a call to [QFile::setFileName](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qfile.html#setFileName) before you open the file. Or declare file after the dialog and pass the filename to the constructor.

Comment: Also if the user cancels the open dialog, you get no file name and couldn't open the file